# ¿Cómo puedo acceder a los datos pivotes de esta tabla?

Tags: php, html, laravel, eloquent

estimados programadores

Mi pregunta es la siguiente

¿Cómo puedo acceder a los datos pivotes de esta tabla?

He probado con

```
$employee = Employee::find(1);
$employee->pivot_created_at;
```

Y siempre me retorna nulo

Este vendría siendo mi modelo

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Employee extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'employee';
    
    protected $fillable = [
        'full_name',
        'identification',
        'cargo'
    ];

    
    public function dates()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Date::class,'date_employee','employee_id','date_id')
                    ->withTimestamps()
                    ->withPivot(
                        'created_at',
                    );
    }
}
```

Y aquí está la tabla ya relacionada con la tabla "dates" y "employee"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tendrías que acceder a la relación y luego a la propiedad pivot de esta `$employee->dates->pivot->created_at`. Igual te sugiero leer la documentacion, para ver cómo se declara la relación y como se la consulta y accede a los datos

Answer (score 3):

El método [timestamps](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#column-method-timestamps) que se usa en las migraciones, creará físicamente los campos  `created_at` y `updated_at`. El único parámetro que acepta es un número indicando precisión.

Por lo anterior, es fácil asumir que el método `withTimestamps` de una relación  `BelongsToMany` sigue la misma lógica. En el código se ve que, por el contrario, el método necesita que pases los nombres de los campos que alojan la fecha de creación y la de actualización, y de lo contrario serán null.

**[Código](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/71c7fe77b432966162a0ca2ec957c033ae591954/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/BelongsToMany.php#L1329_L1337)** :

```
public function withTimestamps($createdAt = null, $updatedAt = null)
{
    $this->withTimestamps = true;

    $this->pivotCreatedAt = $createdAt;
    $this->pivotUpdatedAt = $updatedAt;

    return $this->withPivot($this->createdAt(), $this->updatedAt());
}
```

Cuando se han definido nulos por omisión, los métodos `$this->createdAt()` y  `$this->updatedAt()` terminan siendo una referencia a los timestamps de la tabla padre.

```
public function createdAt()
{
    return $this->pivotCreatedAt ?: $this->parent->getCreatedAtColumn();
}
```

Lo cual me confunde incluso un poco más porque no sabría decir cuál es la tabla padre, si un pivote tiene al menos dos.

En resumen, debieras usar

```
->withTimestamps('created_at')
```

o

```
->withTimestamps('created_at','updated_at')
```

Con eso tu pivote tendría timestamps propios.

Hay [una escueta discusión](https://github.com/laravel/framework/discussions/39728) en los repos de Laravel respecto de esta misma confusión. Me extraña que no haya más.